# C++ cout keeps repeating

Tags: c++, repeat

The line if (!(cin.good())) cout << "No letters" << endl; keeps repeating nonstop if I type in letters, but the other ones work just fine. Can't tell why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    cout << "Please enter a number\n";

    srand(time(0));
    int y = rand();

    while (x != y)
    {
        cin >> x;
        if (!(cin.good()))
           cout << "No letters" << endl;
        else if (x < y)
           cout << "Go higher" << endl;
        else if (x > y)
           cout << "Go lower" << endl;
        else
           cout << "You win!!" << endl;
    }
cin.get();
getchar();
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your invalid input is sitting around in the input buffer. If you just want to throw it all out, you can do this:

```
...
if (!cin.good()) 
{
    cout << "No letters" << endl;
    cin.clear(); // clear error flags
    cin.sync();  // synchronize stream with input source
}
...
```

Comment: @30trix You've got some other kind of typo, then. Possibly forgot the closing curly brace? Or omitted braces altogether?

Answer (score 1):

You need to consume the bad input as it will just remain in the buffer.

Comment: Not sure how, still a beginner

Comment: What he means is that, when you asked cin to read an integer, and it failed, it left the non-integer there, and keeps re-trying to read it.  You need to ask cin to read something that will successfully read that non-integer, like a string, so you can get past it.  (Also note that x is uninitialized.)